# Python Sympy dot with the conjugate not same as norm squared

Tags: python, sympy, simplify

Why does sympy give false on the second Boolean? It correctly gives true on the first Boolean. I thought this last line would be the definition of the norm.

```
from sympy import *

eta_1, eta_2, m = 1, 1, 3

theta_1, theta_2 = symbols("theta_1 theta_2", real=True)
sigma_x = Matrix([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
sigma_y = Matrix([[0, -I], [I, 0]])
sigma_z = Matrix([[1, 0], [0, -1]])

H = eta_1*sin(theta_1)*sigma_x + eta_2*sin(theta_2)*sigma_y + (m-eta_1*cos(theta_1)-eta_2*cos(theta_2))*sigma_z

v = H.eigenvects()
l = v[0][0]
v = v[0][2][0]

n_normal = v/v.norm()
print(simplify(n_normal.norm()**2) == 1)
print(simplify(n_normal.dot(n_normal.H)))
print(simplify(n_normal.dot(n_normal.H)) == 1)
```

I think this has to do with the fact that sympy fails in that

```
simplify(abs(x**2)-x*conjugate(x))==0
```

gives false. Is there some other way to go around this problem, another way to define an inner product that does behave correctly. I'm doing some complicated physics calculations for my thesis and I would really like to check my results with sympy.

**PS**. I'm using `sympy version 1.4dev`.

---

**Edit**: I think the problem is with the fact that simplify doesn't realize that

```
$2*\cos(\theta_1)*cos(\theta_2) - 6*\cos(\theta_1) - 6*\cos(\theta_2) + 11>0\:.$
```

If I replace this in `$n_normal$` with its absolute value it works. I think it is weird that the norm function does this correctly and the simplify of what essentially should be the norm doesn't.

Comment: I also tried it with (n_normal.dot(n_normal.H)).equals(1) method. Unfortunately, this also gives false.